# Google API Domain Admin Access

Tags: python, calendar, google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm working on a script using Python that will access all students' Google calendars using their Google accounts and then add their school schedule into their calendar. I have figured out adding and deleting events and calendars using the API, but my question is how do I add a specific event to a specific calendar under a domain. I am a domain admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The issue was that my client_secrets.json file for oauth 2.0 was set to my personal google account and not the admin account. I cleared the storage.json file where credentials were stored, re ran the program with the admin account logged in, and it worked! Hoped this helps.